# What location does Node.js needs to be installed

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to setup a project to work with Grunt. I need to install Node.js for that to run. I have downloaded and installed Node.js in c:\programfiles.

However when I try running npm install in my project c:\Grunt-proj , I get an error 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Can someone help me with where to install Node.js? I am trying to follow this tutorial-

http://24ways.org/2013/grunt-is-not-weird-and-hard/

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location is fine. I also have installed it in Program Files. But if you need to run the command `npm` from a command prompt then you need to add it to the path of the system. In my case I have `C:\Program Files\nodejs`

Comment: Well I am using command prompt, navigating to my project ie. c:\Grunt-proj and running npm install throught command prompt. Is this what you are trying to say?

Comment: got these errors npm ERR! network getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Grunt-proj. ..and many many more. May be something to do with my network?

Comment: @Pav, if you're behind a proxy you'll need to find out from your network admin what the proxy name is and then [follow these instructions](http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy).